# How to get system DOWNTIME through command prompt

Tags: java, cmd

I am building one application using Spring 4.0 where, I need to know System downtime in my application.

I referred lot of site but I didn't get anything.

If I got to know what is the command for getting system downtime then I can implement on java program..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: to know up time we use **net statistics server** .. then what is the command for downtime. @chrylis

Comment: downtime = elapsed time - uptime

Comment: then how to get **elapsed time** in cmd ??? @DavidPostill

Comment: elapsed time = current time - start time

Comment: "downtime" = "when went the server down" or "how long was the server down" ?

Comment: Ya exactly when went the server down and I guess I got the solution but I don't know if it is the correct way to do or not. That's way i posted this question. @Stephan

Comment: with programming, there is no "**the** correct way". If it works, use it. If you are not satisfied with it, show us your code and we can discuss it.

Comment: @Stephan Thanks I would like to discuss about it. SO my idea is like, If we will see **C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\System.evtx** In System.evtx file all information is there. We can find here system downtime where **Event Id = 6006** But the thing is we can't read this file directly but we can convert this file into excel format. But the problem is when I am coping this file (System.evtx) to c:\ drive or under C:\Windows\ drive I am able to read and convert it into excel format but I don't know why i am unable to read it from its original path(C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\System.evtx).

Answer (score 1):

Powershell has an easy way to get the last shutdown date-time:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName System -InstanceId 6006 -newest 1
```

To get the date only:

```
(Get-EventLog -LogName System -InstanceId 6006 -newest 1).timeGenerated
```

To get the date in the desired format (modify to your needs):

```
get-date((Get-EventLog -LogName System -InstanceId 6006 -newest 1).timeGenerated) -format yyyyMMdd
```

To execute it from `cmd`:

```
powershell get-date((Get-EventLog -LogName System -InstanceId 6006 -newest 1).timeGenerated) -format yyyyMMdd
```

`cmd`'s way to get the output of a command is a `for` (you need to escape closing parantheses within the command):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell get-date((Get-EventLog -LogName System -InstanceId 158 -newest 1^).timeGenerated^) -format yyyyMMdd') do set lastShutdown=%%a
```

(Note: `%%a` syntax is for use in batch files. To use it directly from command line, use a single `%`only: `%a`)